# Почему в моём коде происходит ошибка "reached end of file while parsing"?

Tags: java

Ни как не могу понять, где ошибка в коде.

Текст ошибки:

> reached end of file while parsing

Код:

```
    double rubles = 150.00;
    System.out.println("Сейчас у 
    вас на счёте " + rubles + " 
    рублей."); 
    // Напечатайте значение
```

Comment: Добавь в вопрос весь код полностью

Comment: Скорее всего где-то в коде не закрыта фигурная скобка

Answer (score 2):

#### Про ошибку, которую получаете Вы

Я  *догадываюсь*, какой у вас код. У вас есть какой-то класс (пусть это будет класс `Test`) и у вас есть в этом классе метод `main()`. Но последней фигурной скобки у вас нет:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double rubles = 150.00;
        System.out.println("Сейчас у 
        вас на счёте " + rubles + " 
        рублей."); 
    }
} //Вот этой фигурной скобки у вас нет.
```

#### Про ваш код

Добавляем фигурную скобку в конце. Компилируем и думаем: сейчас всё будет хорошо, это точно...
 Но получаем следующие ошибки:

```
/Test.java:4: error: unclosed string literal
    System.out.println("Сейчас у 
                       ^
/Test.java:5: error: ';' expected
    вас на счёте " + rubles + " 
          ^
/Test.java:5: error: not a statement
    вас на счёте " + rubles + " 
           ^
/Test.java:5: error: ';' expected
    вас на счёте " + rubles + " 
                ^
/Test.java:6: error: unclosed string literal
    рублей."); 
           ^
/Test.java:6: error: not a statement
    рублей."); 
          ^
6 errors
```

Все эти ошибки происходят по той причине, что вы разрываете строку на несколько частей (нажимаете <kbd>enter</kbd> и закрываете кавычку на следующей строке):

```
 System.out.println("Сейчас у 
 вас на счёте " + rubles + " 
 рублей.");
```

Есть 2 варианта решения проблемы.

- Ограничиться одной строкой:

```java
System.out.println("Сейчас у вас на счёте " + rubles + " рублей.");
```

- Складывать строки между собой с помощью оператора `+`. На это вы потратите больше памяти и в данном случае это бессмысленно и даже вредно, ибо строки у вас не такие уж длинные, а память тратится зря. Но этот вариант был бы логичен, если бы строки были длинные и не умещались бы в экран:

```
 System.out.println("очень очень очень очень очень очень" + 
 "очень очень очень очень очень длинная строка");
```